# how to stop queue job after finish its execution automatically in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I use queue job after (a user) registered, it sent an email for verifying, I set a delay (10 second) to run the job.

**but the issue is that:**

- the queue job runs and executes the verifying email fine, but it still running in the background forever, and this consumes the resources:

[image]

how to stop it automatically after the execution of the job?

**Route:**

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'guest:web'], function(){
    Route::get('/register', [registerController::class,'register'])->name('site.register');
    Route::match(['get','post'],'/register-create', [registerController::class,'create'])->name('site.register.create');
});
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function create(RegisterRequest $request)
{
     $user = User::create([
        'firstName' => $request->firstName,
        'middleName' => $request->middleName,
        'lastName' => $request->lastName,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
    $on = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addSecond(10);
     dispatch(new VerifyEmailJob($user))->delay($on);
    return redirect()->route('landingPage')->with(['success'=>'We sent verifying email check it']);
}
```

**queue job:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class VerifyEmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user= $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Mail::to($this->user->email)->send(new VerifyEmail($this->user));

    }
}
```

**Mail class:**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class VerifyEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        return $this->subject('Mail from Oneme')
            ->view('site.auth.verifyEmail',compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Any Help please

Comment: thats not the job running for ever, that is the queue worker that is still running and waiting for jobs to run

Comment: Thanks for replay, So how to stop it automatically

Comment: you only want to process 1 job on the queue then stop?

Comment: yes, particulary this job

Comment: if you want the worker to only process 1 job you need to add `--once` ... `php artisan queue:work --once`

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to run this command automatically without write it manually  after a particular job.

Comment: you can't specify what job is to be ran or anything like that, it just runs the next job on the queue ... why do you not want the queue worker running?   you can tell the worker to stop when the queue is empty (it will process all the jobs until there are none left)

Comment: cuz it will consumes the resources if still running

Comment: @MahmoudDiab no sir, it is a worker, it is listening for jobs to run... if you don't want to have a listener in the background then change your `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `sync` so any event and job executes when you dispatch them directly on that request... you are not understand what `queue:listener` or `queue:work` is for...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm not familiar with queue job in Laravel, so I thought that worker consumes the resources as long as it's running.

Answer (score 1):

according to the Laravel documentation you have many options to handle the processing of you queue. I think you can use this one: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#processing-all-queued-jobs-then-exiting